# How do you hold down left click with python?

Tags: python, keyboard, click, pyautogui

I know that you can hold down certain keys with pyautogui, but is there a way to hold down the left click key with keyDown and keyUp (or with another module)? Thanks in advance if you help.

Comment: Did you mean: [pyautogui.mouseDown()](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#the-mousedown-and-mouseup-functions)

Comment: Yes I did actually, thanks! If you post this as an answer Ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#the-mousedown-and-mouseup-functions) you can use `mouseDown()`:

```py
>>> pyautogui.mouseDown(); pyautogui.mouseUp()  # does the same thing as a left-button mouse click
>>> pyautogui.mouseDown(button='right')  # press the right button down
>>> pyautogui.mouseUp(button='right', x=100, y=200)  # move the mouse to 100, 200, then release the right button up.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pyautogui.click()                   # Left click
pyautogui.click(button='right')     # Right click
```

[This](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) is the docs for the mouse control functions of pyautogui.